# When last was the OSI model layer updated

Tags: tcp, linux, udp, osi

since reading about the OSI model, which was created since 1984. My question is has there been any revision on the model. Or did the delegate who design the OSI model made it for everlasting.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSI model is [ISO/IEC 7498-1:1994](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=20269). It was last updated in 1994, and it had corrections applied in 1996. The seven-layer model itself has not really changed since it was first described, but the document containing it is in its second edition.